# tablix returns only 1 record for dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix on an SSRS report:

[image]

When I run the report it only returns 1 record!

I did a sql server trace, and the query that is being executed is returning 14 rows.

On the same report, I dropped another table, and put just one field on it, and it returns 14 as expected. I noticed that the difference between the one that works and that one that doesnt is:

[image]

How can I get those 3 horizontal lines on the one that doesn't work?

What could be my issue? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The screen shot shows you don't have any groups.  You deleted the details group from the Tablix.  You can add it back in by inserting a new group or building a new tablix object from scratch.

To add a group, click on a cell in the row that should have a group, in this case the [ReferredBy] cell.  Select Add Group -> Row Group -> Adjacent Above.  If your data is already grouped at the correct level of granularity, then select Show detail data in the Tablix Group screen.  This will add the details triple bar in a row above your current row.  If you need to group on something, then pick the field to group on.  This will add a ) in a row above your current row.  Copy and paste the contents of the cells in your existing row into the new row and delete your original row.

Comment: thanks !! how can i insert a new group? when i right click, i do not have the option to insert

Comment: would this one be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046678/how-to-associate-two-fields

Comment: Added detailed instructions.

Answer (score 5):

One row when you expect multiple sounds like a grouping issue.  Debugging something like this I would create a new table element below the current one and drag and drop a single column from the dataset.  If it returns 14 you know it is not the dataset being evaluated as a problem but the table's expression.  If it is also only returning one you probably have a predicate, filter expression, or parameter setting limiting the scope down as well.

Comment: thank you very much for your generous advice, i will troubleshoot like you suggested and get back within a few minutes

Comment: you are definitely right. i dropped another table underneath and got 14 !!

Comment: I agree with 'Registered User' you may have lost a 'details' level.  This happens at times if you add levels and then you lose scope of where the heirarchy is at.  Add a child to the existing table or else you can rebuild from a brand new table and recreate it from scratch to see what is happening.

Comment: would this one be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046678/how-to-associate-two-fields

Comment: Yes it could be, you have to watch at all times your groupings.  I generally add one grouping at a time and test results.  When you get more than three groupings you have to be careful what is the lowest level and what the in between are doing.

Comment: i meant could you help me wiht that question :) i asked that one as well

Comment: In my case this was  a 'details' group issue ,i have added new table and it works, is there any way to add this group without creating new table from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you set the expression for Textbox and not for the RowGroup.
Just find the Group Properties then put the same expression in Group On.