# how to associate two fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there's the yellow/orange bracket.

I believe that I need the bracket to cover both fields like this:

[image]

Because there's a 1:1 relationship between the two fields, and I want them to be displayed like this:

```
Field1
Field2
Field1
Field2
```

**How can I associate them together like this?**

Currently it's reporting this way:

```
Field1
Field1
Field1
Field2
Field2
Field2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this potentially as it may be simpler than getting into something already happening wrong:

1. Add a new details row
2. verify both details row return data of one of each for each data line in a dataset
3. Add a grouping and see if that works.

If that does not work, never tried this before sorry, then I would create a subreport that does the grouping and takes a parameter that is at the group level then next a subreport that accounts for two lines.  I have done that before :)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the Details row.  Insert Rows -> Inside Group - Above.